# SharpSVN ForceCredentials overwrites authentication cache

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

SVN, like every mature tool used for lots of different purposes, is complex. SharpSVN tries to expose all SVN features programmatically, so it is complex, too. I just tried to authorize a tool with a given username/password on a machine where TortioseSVN is used for other purposes on the same SVN server (realm).

```
var client = new SvnClient();
client.Authentication.ForceCredentials("userName", "password");
```

Unfortunately, this replaced the existing credentials cached by TortioseSVN to these used by the tool. Is there a simple way to avoid overwriting the authentication cache and also ignore what is in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the possibilities are endless by subscribing to the `UserNameHandlers` and `UserNamePasswordHandlers` events of the `client.Authentication` property, the simplest solution seems to be this:

```
var client = new SvnClient();
client.Authentication.Clear();
client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password");
```